# Обработка обязательных и необязательных значений radio через js

Tags: input, html, javascript

У меня есть огромное множество полей выбора `<input type="radio">`. Все как положено, у каждой группы отдельные name. Но необходимо завершать работу скрипта, если у кнопок с определенными name не нажата хотя-бы одна кнопка.

Для удобства настрочил примерчик [вот тут](http://jsfiddle.net/qgVzA/1/). У меня же первые три элемента массива button являются обязательными.

**И как быть, если у меня кол-во элементов не постоянное? "на разных страницах от 2 до 6"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qgVzA/2/

Comment: @eicto а как быть, если у меня кол-во элементов не постоянное? "на разных страницах от 2 до 6"

Comment: Вверх вопрос